# Angularjs and jasmine, testing promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test my controller which calls at when it starts a service returning a promise containing the username. It always fails and I can't see why.

**Module**:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('dilib', [
            // Angular modules
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngRoute',

            // Custom modules
            'dilib.layout',

            // 3rd Party Modules
            'LocalStorageModule',
            'restangular'
    ])
        .config(function (RestangularProvider) {

            RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost/services/webapi/');

        })
        .config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {

            localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('dilib');

        });
})();
```

**Controller**:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'requestAuthorizationController';

    angular
        .module('dilib')
        .controller(controllerId, requestAuthorizationController);

    requestAuthorizationController.$inject = ['requestAuthorizationService'];

    function requestAuthorizationController(requestAuthorizationService) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.username = undefined;

        activate();

        function activate() {

            return requestAuthorizationService.requestAuthorization().then(function (result) {

                vm.username = result;

                return vm.username;

            });

        }

    }
})();
```

**Service**:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var serviceId = 'requestAuthorizationService';

  angular
    .module('dilib')
    .service(serviceId, requestAuthorizationService);

  requestAuthorizationService.$inject = ['$q'];

  function requestAuthorizationService($q) {

    //API
    var service = {

      requestAuthorization: requestAuthorization,
    }

    return service;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function requestAuthorization(user) {

      var defer = $q.defer();

      defer.resolve('visitor');

      return defer.promise;
    }

  }
})();
```

**Spec**:

```
//requestAuthorizationController Specification

'use strict';

describe('requestAuthorizationController Specification', function() {

    var RestangularProvider,
        localStorageServiceProvider,
        controller,
        requestAuthorizationServiceMock,
        $rootScope,
        scope;

    beforeEach(function () {

        angular.module('ngAnimate', []);
        angular.module('ngRoute', []);
        angular.module('dilib.layout', []);
        //angular.module('LocalStorageModule', []);
        angular.module('http-auth-interceptor', []);
        //angular.module('restangular', []);

    });

    beforeEach(function() {

        module('dilib', function(_RestangularProvider_, _localStorageServiceProvider_, $provide) {

            RestangularProvider = _RestangularProvider_;
            localStorageServiceProvider = _localStorageServiceProvider_;

            $provide.service('requestAuthorizationService', function ($q) {
                this.requestAuthorization = jasmine.createSpy('requestAuthorization').and.callFake(function(result) {

                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    defer.resolve('visitor');
                    return defer.promise;

                });
            });

        });

    });

    beforeEach(inject());

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_, requestAuthorizationService) {

        controller = $controller;
        requestAuthorizationServiceMock = requestAuthorizationService;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

    }));

    it('Provides the authenticated user name', function() {

        var vm = controller('requestAuthorizationController');
        expect(vm.username).toBe('visitor');

    });

});
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8vl1LBYSzPsQmmf5jSZa?p=preview).

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I forgot to call $rootScope.$apply(). Now looks like this.

```
it('Provides the authenticated user name', function() {

        var vm = controller('requestAuthorizationController');
        expect(vm.username).toBe('visitor');

    });
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8vl1LBYSzPsQmmf5jSZa?p=preview) is the plunker.